# python lowercase function for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, for-loop

I am trying to create a function to lower case all inputs.

in the end I should be able to lowercase:

```
result = lowerList('Jen', 'Suzie')
print(result)
```

so far I have:

```
def lowerList(input1, input2):
  myList = [input1, input2]
  for x in myList:
    return(x.lower())

result = lowerlist('Jen', 'Suzie')
print(result)
```

> jen

So right now I am only able to get the first input.  Also how can I modify this to loop continuously for any number of inputs without modifying the function?

Comment: Do not return, when you return you exit the function

Comment: *without modifying the function?*  <--  you have to modify the function

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that your returning on the first iteration of your for loop, after you've only operated on *one* element. You need to build up a *list* of modified values, then return the *whole* list.

You could do this manually:

```
def lower_list(*args):
    strings = []
    for string in args:
        strings.append(string.lower())
    return strings
```

But a simpler and more elegant solution is to use a list comprehension:

```
def lower_list(*args):
    return [string.lower() for string in args]
```

Another option if you perfer it, is to use a generator;

```
def lower_list(*args):
    for string in args:
        yield string.lower()
```

And it would be used like so:

```
>>> str_gen = lower_list('Hello', 'WORld', 'Name', 'BUCKs')
>>> next(str_gen)
'hello'
>>> next(str_gen)
'world'
>>> next(str_gen)
'name'
>>> # etc...
```

Or if you need the entire list of strings at once:

```
>>> list(lower_list('Hello', 'WORld', 'Name', 'BUCKs'))
['hello', 'world', 'name', 'bucks']
```

Comment: Thanks @Christian Dean all great answers for understanding for loop functions better

Comment: @pdangelo4 Glad I could help out :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
def to_lower(*args):                      
    return [arg.lower() for arg in args]  

>>> to_lower('SPAM', 'Eggs')
['spam', 'eggs']
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not return in loop which aborts the for loop right there. Instead create a new list append the lowered elements to it inside the for loop amd return once the loop is done.

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you return the for loop stops. What you should do is append the result string to a list and return it.
Using your code as base:

```
def lowerList(input1, input2):
  myList = [input1, input2]
  l = []
  for x in myList:
    l.append(x.lower())
  return l

result = lowerList('Jen', 'Suzie')
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how big your lists are going to get, it may even be more efficient to use generators:

```
def to_lower(*args):                      
    for arg in args:
        yield arg.lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are only getting the first input is because you are only returning the first input. After you return from a function, you cannot get back inside that function unless you call it again.

> for x in myList:
>       return(x.lower())

Instead, you can do something like this:

```
def lowerList(myList):
  normalList = []
  for x in myList:
    normalList.append(x.lower())
  return normalList

normalList = ['Jen', 'Suzie']
result = lowerList(normalList)
print(result)
```

Return a new list where all the items are lowercased, and print that.

Hope this helps!